# Доступ к Файловой Системе JFS

Tags: linux, unix, файловая-система

Есть ли утилита, для доступа к *nix файловой системе JFS, из под Windows?

Что-то вроде Linux Reader или Exr2Fsd но поддерживающий JFS

Comment: А в последнем Creator Pack (или как-то так) обновлении Win10 ничего такого не реализовали? Вроде там анонсировали ещё более тесное взаимодействие с Linux.

Answer (score 0):

FSproxy http://nadrin.github.io/fsproxy/wikka5bf1.html?wakka=HomePage is a small application that runs in the system tray and lets you access GNU/Linux partitions from within Microsoft Windows. The list of detected partitions is always availible at \fsproxy and a single one can easily be mapped to a network drive using address like \fsproxy\. By default partitions are mounted as read-only but experimental write support can be enabled. FSproxy currently supports: ext2, ext3, ext4, reiserfs, jfs, xfs and few other filesystems.